# proof regarding kurtosis

Tags: statistics

I am trying to manipulate an expression about kurtosis.

It says that $kurt(X)=\frac{V_4(X)}{\sigma^4}-3$, $V_4(X)=E[(X-\mu)^4]$

Then it states that $kurt(\bar{X})=\frac{k}{n}$, where $k = kurt(X_i)$. We assume iid.

I want to prove the last result.

In order to prove it  seems I have to show that:

$\frac{E[(X-\mu)^4]}{\sigma^4*n}-3/n=\frac{E[(\bar{X}-\mu)^4]}{\sigma^4/n^2}-3$.

However it seems difficult to show that these two are equal. Any tips? I tried multiplying out the parenthesis in each case, but I get stuck because for instance after using the formula $E[Z^2]=V(Z)+E(Z)^2$, I get stuck with for instance $V(\bar{X}^2)$, which I do not know how to reduce to get rid of the mean and represent it in terms of X. And I also get a problem with $E(\bar{X}^3)$ I don't know how to reduce this.

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: What are $i$ and $n$ and $\bar{X}$?

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article on kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis)? The explanation there seems reasonably clear.

Comment: @DilipSarwate On Wikipedia they define $\gamma_2=\frac{k_4}{k_2^2}=\frac{\mu_4}{\sigma^4}-3$. But they do not define $k_2$ and $k_4$ as far as I see?, if only one were undefined it would understand. Also they use that $k_4[\Sigma X_i]=n*k_4[X_i]$. How is this shown?